# How transform observable into another observable

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

I'm starting with Rxjs for Angular 6 and I have some doubts about how accomplish this:

I have a card list component which will show list with items fetched from a service which returns an observable. Data type items are different. And service observable may be updated with new items so card list should display this new items.

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  papers$:Observable<Paper[]>;

  papersPublished$:Observable<DataCard[]>;
  papersOnReview$:Observable<DataCard[]>;
  papersSubmitted$:Observable<DataCard[]>;

  constructor(private publicationService: PublicationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.papers$ = merge(
      this.publicationService.getAllPapersOnState("Submitted"),
      this.publicationService.getAllPapersOnState("OnReview"),
      this.publicationService.getAllPapersOnState("Published")
    );

        this.papersSubmitted$ = this.papers$.pipe(map(paper => [HomeComponent.paperToCard(paper,'Read', 'Review')]));
        this.papersOnReview$ = this.papers$.pipe(map(paper => [HomeComponent.paperToCard(paper,'Read', 'Accept')]));
        this.papersPublished$ = this.papers$.pipe(map(paper => [HomeComponent.paperToCard(paper,'Read', '')]));
      }

  private static paperToCard(paper, action_1_name, action_2_name): DataCard {
        // ... other code ...
  }
}

<app-cardlist
  [title]="'Published'"
  [description]="'Last science papers published. Yay!'"
  [items$]="papersPublished$"></app-cardlist>
<app-cardlist
  [title]="'On Review'"
  [description]="'Last papers on review. On publish way!'"
  [items$]="papersOnReview$"></app-cardlist>
<app-cardlist
  [title]="'Submitted'"
  [description]="'Last papers submitted for reviewing. Be the first one to check them!'"
  [items$]="papersSubmitted$"></app-cardlist>



export class PublicationService {
 // ... more code ...
 getAllPapersOnState(state: string): Observable<Paper[]> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.WF_SC.deployed().then(instance => {

        // State changed watcher to update on-live the observable
        const event = instance.AssetStateChanged({});
        event.on('data', (data) => {
          console.log('StateChanged catched!');
          this.getPaper((data['args']['assetAddress'])).then((paper) => observer.next(paper));
        });

        return instance.findAssetsByState.call(state);
      }).then(addresses => {
        addresses.forEach((address) => this.getPaper(address).then((paper) => observer.next(paper)));
      });
    });
  }
}


export class CardlistComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() items$: Observable<DataCard[]>;

}

<div *ngIf="(items$ | async)" class="card-deck">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <!-- Other code -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that only last item is displayed on the list. How can I transform `papers$:Observable<Paper[]>` into `$papersSubmitted$:Observable<DataCard[]>` to be able pass it to `CardlistComponent` ?

Comment: Please show how you're calling your `CardlistComponent` from the home one. Your `papersSubmitted$` and similar observables look suspicious though, they look like they'll contain all papers' cards instead of only the submitted/review/published ones.

Comment: Yes, filter is not yet implemented. Just now three list should show the same info. The idea was to have one observable with all papers and later filter to pass them into CardList. I attached code below HomeComponent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
this.papersSubmitted$ = this.papers$.pipe(
  map((papers: Paper[]) => 
    papers.map((paper: Paper) => HomeComponent.paperToCard(paper, 'Read', 'Review')
  )
);
```

Same for all similar ones (and you should of course also filter them, as you mentioned in the comments).

Then, in your Service, do this:

```
return Observable.create(observer => {
  // ...
}).pipe(toArray());
```

to return an `Observable<Paper[]>` instead of an `Observable<Paper>`.

Comment: Mmh... this display an error: "TypeError: papers.map is not a function". A console.log(papers) shows one paper instead of an array. I think because the service performances observer.next(paper); and it should be observer.next([paper]);